# How can I change a signal only if a condition is met, and otherwise return the signal's old value without having the signal as an input?

Tags: simulink

I am working on converting code into simulink blocks, and this issue is coming up repeatedly in this task.

Take this pseudocode:

```
int number = 0; // Global variable
updateNumber()
{
   if(externalCondition)
   then number++; // The number is edited based on an external condition.
   // else do nothing;
}
main
{
   for(true)
   {
      updateNumber();
   }
}
```

We have a global variable, with a default value of 0.

Then, when we call a function `updateNumber` that variable is changed based on an external condition.

I have to create a Simulink model for the *updateNumber* function, with no inputs, but with *number* as its output.

*number* should only change its value if the condition is met, else it shall keep its previous value. Just like in the pseudocode.

I suspect I can use enabled subsystems to achieve this, but I just can't see how this can be done in Simulink.

The main problem is: how can I **not** change the value of the number when the condition is not met? Can I have an if block that outputs "something or nothing" based on the condition?

[This is what I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt2Kb.png), but even when the enabled subsystem's signal is set to false the subsystem runs and sets the value to 15.

[Here's another illustration of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlD3z.png).

Answer (score 0):

Stateflow should solve it. Just increment number everytime condition is met

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).